# how to call a native alert box while using phonegap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

Below is my code but its not working,  the error function is calling only

Native plugin

```
package com.gami.fre;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ConfirmBox extends Plugin {

    public static final String NATIVE_ACTION_STRING="nativeAction";       
    public static final String SUCCESS_PARAMETER="success"; 
    public Context context;
    public int result=0;

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId) 
    {

          Log.d("HelloPlugin", "PhoneGap/Cordova!");             
          //only perform the action if it is the one that should be invoked 


          if (NATIVE_ACTION_STRING.equals(action))
          {                   
              String resultType = null;                    

              try {                         
                   resultType = data.getString(0);                   
                  }                    
              catch (Exception ex) {  

                  Log.d("HelloPlugin", ex.toString());          
                  }                    

              if (resultType.equals(SUCCESS_PARAMETER))
                {          
                  Log.d("hisu", resultType);
                  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);

                        // set title
                        //alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Are you sure want to Exit!")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
                                {
                                    //ConfirmBox.this.finish();
                                }
                              })
                            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
                                {

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                            // create alert dialog
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();
 return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, result);

                }      
             else 
             {                      
                  return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Oops, Error :(");                 
             }           
        } 

    return null;

    }

}
```

**phone gap call**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function callNativePlugin( returnSuccess ) 
{    
 Helo.callNativeFunction( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, returnSuccess ); 

} 

function nativePluginResultHandler (result)
 {    
    //alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result ); 

 } 

 function nativePluginErrorHandler (error)
 {    

 alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error );

 }
```

only the error function is calling every time; success callling is happening but skipped immediatly after the first line. i.e after log printing its skipped from the function and showing error: NULL

Please help to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Hope, addJavascriptInterface() will help you calling native android functions from javascript

Ex:

Native code: ***webview.addJavascriptInterface(this.Activity,"SomeKey");***

Javascript :

Here you can call native functions as

***window.SomeKey.execute()***    //execute is the native function

Comment: Thank you I found a solution: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the best solution rather than a plugin.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

Answer (score 0):

I created this earlier this year. I am not too sure if it still works with the current Phonegap. It's a plugin that I created to allow you to create an AlertList and return you the user's selection.

https://github.com/kidino/phonegap-alertdialoglist-plugin

[image: Example of the Android AlertList Dialog for Phonegap]

Generally, what you need to do in your Javascript is to create an array. The first item will become the title for the AlertList. And then you call the showlist() function and pass the array as parameter. Check out the example in the www folder in the repo.

```
<script>
    var fruitlist = [
                      "The Fruit List Title", // this is the title 
                      "Orange", 
                      "Apple", 
                      "Watermelon", 
                      "Papaya", 
                      "Banana", 
                      "Pear" 
              ];

    function showlist(thelist) {
            cordova.exec(
                    function(listitem) {
                            alert( "You selected "+ thelist[listitem] );
                    }, 
                    function(error) {
                            alert("Error Occured");
                    }, "AlertList", "alertlist", thelist );
    }
</script>
```

In your HTML, you can have something like:

```
<h1><a href="javascript:showlist(fruitlist)">FRUITS</a></h1>
```